# Unable to see ifconfig output using paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

I am using below code to execute commands on a remote machine,

```
import paramiko
import os
dssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
dssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
dssh.connect('192.168.1.5', username='root', password='asdfghhh')

import os

stdin, stdout, stderr = dssh.exec_command('ls')
print stdout.read()
stdin, stdout, stderr = dssh.exec_command('ifconfig')
print stdout.read()
stdin, stdout, stderr = dssh.exec_command('ps')
print stdout.read()
dssh.close()
```

when I execute the program, Its able to show the ls and ps as well as other commands output.
however ifconfig o/p is not observed.

any idea how to solve this problems?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: What does `print stderr.read()` say?

Comment: `print stderr.read()` doesn't show any message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your server may be discriminating between interactive and non-interactive SSH sessions, running different startup scripts for the different sessions. Try running `echo $PATH` on the remote host through the paramiko SSH session and a regular interactive one and compare the outputs.

For a workaround you can do a `which ifconfig` on the remote server in an interactive session to get the absolute path and use that in your paramiko command.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = dssh.exec_command('/abs/path/to/ifconfig')
```

**NOTE**
On one of my hosts the result of `echo $PATH` from the paramiko SSH client was `/usr/bin:/bin`, while in an interactive session it was `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`, and `ifconfig` was indeed located in `/usr/sbin`, i.e. outside the path of the paramiko session.

Answer (score 1):

To get the output for certain application binaries you must use the flag: *get_pty=True*

I'm still looking for the reason it happens for some commands, it's for me unknown yet. However the way I found to workaround this problem is shown in the example below:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('10.2.0.230', username='ibmsys1', password='passw0rd', timeout=5)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('/sbin/ifconfig', timeout=3, get_pty=True)

print stdout.read()
```

Usually I would run: 
`#stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('/sbin/ifconfig')`

in my example, I've just added 2 new flags, `timeout=3` and `get_pty=True`
This solved my problem. The timeout flag is not related, however I always use it as good practice. The point here is the use of the get_pty=True
PS. I would recommend do not trust on the system $PATH, always input the full path for the application to be run, e.g: /usr/bin/my_binary or in your case /sbin/ifconfig

I hope this may help you to workaround the problem. 
Good luck!