# Using paramiko to execute dd command but get nothing return

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, paramiko

I use python paramiko module to execute dd command remotely like below:

```
paramiko.util.log_to_file('paramiko.log')
s = paramiko.SSHClient()
s.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
s.connect('ip', 22, "account", "password")

command = r"dd if=/dev/zero of=/test bs=4M count=1024 oflag=direct"
stdin, stdout, stderr = s.exec_command( command )
print( stdout.read().strip() )
```

But I get nothing return string(only a null line) from stdout.read(), what's the reasons about that?

PS: I can get the result when I write the command directly on CLI.

Answer (score 1):

did you check `stderr`? Probably the command did not execute properly.

Comment: Yes, but there is None in stderr. Therefore I think the command is executed successfully.

Comment: There is a suggestion in another thread, to use full path to the binary: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17828015/2417347

Comment: OK, I will try to create an user thread to handle this dd command. But the full path isn't the problem for this question...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check its success then try to check its return code. If it is zero then it is success.

You need to use Paramiko transport to check the return code

```
chan = s.get_transport().open_session()

# Execute thecommand
chan.exec_command(cmd)
print chan.recv_exit_status() # This will print its return code
```

Comment: Thanks for your replying. The return code is '0', so I think the command is executed by paramiko successfully. BTW, is there any possible caused by the dd command originally that I can't get any output in stdout.read()?

Comment: Hmmmm.... its strange... have you tried to execute command manually.. may be your version of dd is not generating any output.. just a guess